# USB Hub not working. lsusb -v and dmesg disagree on whether it is Self Powered or Bus Powered

Tags: usb, power-management, 22.10

I'm trying to use the [Sabrent HB-BU10](https://sabrent.com/products/hb-bu10) with Ubuntu 22.10 running on a Dell 7490 notebook.

With nothing plugged into USB, the system reports the following internal hubs with lsusb -v:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

With only the powered hub (no devices connected) plugged into the system, lsusb -v reports two new hubs (apparently USB2 and USB3 are each enumerated).  I've inserted a few additional lines from the long listing:

```
Bus 002 Device 029: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub  (2)
      iProduct                2 USB3.2 Hub
      bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      MaxPower                0mA
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (105)  Native
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub  (1017)
      iProduct                2 USB2.1 Hub
      MaxPower                0mA
      bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  (1390)  Native
```

The hub is correctly identified as "Self Powered" since it has an external power supply providing 60W.

However when the hub only (no devices) is plugged into any USB port on the computer, this is seen:

```
$ sudo dmesg
[51415.379442] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[51415.543357] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=5411, bcdDevice= 0.02
[51415.543370] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[51415.543377] usb 1-2: Product: USB2.1 Hub
[51415.543381] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Generic
[51415.547300] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[51415.548519] hub 1-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[51415.663869] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[51415.699153] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0411, bcdDevice= 0.02
[51415.699157] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[51415.699159] usb 2-3: Product: USB3.2 Hub
[51415.699160] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Generic
[51415.706866] hub 2-3:1.0: USB hub found
[51415.708501] hub 2-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[51415.847274] usb 1-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[51415.959902] usb 1-2.4: can't connect bus-powered hub to this port
[51416.045174] usb 2-3.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[51416.071928] usb 2-3.4: can't connect bus-powered hub to this port
```

Furthermore if any device is plugged into the hub, then this message is also logged:

```
usb 2-3.2: rejected 1 configuration due to insufficient available bus power
```

Why does the system think the hub is bus powered, with power limits, when in fact it is self powered, and correctly identified in lsusb?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the hub is defective. It is unclear if the specific unit is defective, or the design.

After searching and studying the USB subsystem for hours, I was getting nowhere. After concluding that the hub was reporting itself as bus-powered when it was self-powered, I went and purchased a new hub.
I found one from [Vantec](https://www.microcenter.com/product/603779/10-Port_USB_31_Hub_with_Power_Adapter) with similar capabilities.

It worked fine. No errors were reported in dmesg:

```
[59222.814154] usb 2-4.1.1: Product: USB3.0 Hub
[59222.814155] usb 2-4.1.1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[59222.814157] usb 2-4.1.1: SerialNumber: 000000000
[59222.816135] hub 2-4.1.1:1.0: USB hub found
[59222.816286] hub 2-4.1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
```